# Defining an object key as the value of a given variable and not the name of variable itself

Tags: javascript, html

Context: I'm using google charts to create a pie chart and I want to make the last index fixed to color red. To do this, I'm saving a variable as indices that will essentially update the value with the latest index added. I'm then passing to a variable `i` to become the key of an object that will define the color, but it seems as if google charts doesn't register the variable `i` and only accepts the numbers from 0,1,2,3,etc.

```
let indices = indexSum;
for (let i = 1; i <= indices; i++) {
  var lossColor = {
    i: { color: "red" },
  };
}
```

In the object that is being saved as `lossColor`, it will work if I use the number `1` for example as the key, but it won't work if I use `i`. I'm doing this to keep track of the amount of indices created by the user so that the last index will always be colored red.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn("string", "Ativo");
  data.addColumn("number", "Quota");
  data.addRows([
    ...slices.map((slice) => [slice.ativo, slice.quota]),
    ["Loss", perda],
  ]);
  //Styling
  let options = {
    legend: "right",
    pieHole: 0.5,
    legend: { textStyle: { color: "gray" } },
    pieSliceText: "value",
    slices: lossColor,
    colors: ["#728FCE", "#FBB117", "#6AA121", "#4863A0", "#7D0552", "#FF0000"],
    backgroundColor: "#22252a",
    chartArea: {
      left: 50,
      right: 50,
      top: 70,
    },
    width: "100%",
    height: "500px",
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
    document.getElementById("piechart")
  );

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Is there a way so that the key of the object `lossColor` retrieves the number itself and not just `i` as this doesn't seem to be accepted by google charts (there is no error being thrown, it just simply doesn't register the color).

[It should appear the number "1" or "2" instead of "i", for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stsoi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `i: { color: "red" }` is basically creating an object with a key called `i`. To create an object with a key of the *value* of `i`, you can firstly initialise an empty object - `let myObj = {};`, then set the property like so - `myObj[i] = "red";`.

Here is the updated code:

```js
let indices = indexSum;
var lossColor = {};

for (let i = 1; i <= indices; i++) {
  lossColor[i] = { color: "red" };
}
```

Also, use `lossColor` as a *constant*, i.e. outside the loop, so that it isn't emptied every time it is looped over.

**Edit: You can do the same thing with ES6+ as well, as @MikhailSemikolenov pointed out.**

```js
let indices = indexSum;
var lossColor = {};

for (let i = 1; i <= indices; i++) {
  lossColor = { ...lossColor, [i]: { color: "red" } }
}
```

Comment: Also, when you really need to use variable value as a key in object literal, you can do it with ES6+ syntax like this `let variable = 'foo'; let obj = {[variable]:'bar'} ` - now obj is `{foo:'bar'}`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is working, however, every slice is now turning red. I have the `colors` variable that will be used to shuffle between different colors, but I guess I'll have to figure out how to only make the last index become red without affecting the other slices (possibly put the last slice as red and "reset" the others somehow at the beginning of the for loop)

Comment: @MikhailSemikolenov You're absolutely right my friend! But I wasn't sure whether to prefer ES6. Gonna edit the answer to add it as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set the `lossColor` key to be the value of `i`, you can't do it the way you're showing. According to [MDN - Object Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) you have to do the following, to create a key with the value of a variable:

```
let lossColor[i] = { color: "red" }
```

By the way you're doing, you will create an object with the key `i` and not with the value of `i`